# What is meant by {Author_name}* (with asterisk) in Version Control "Log" window of Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I am working on a project with one of my teammates. Today I just observed a very strange thing which is this `*(Asterisk)` with the `Author Name` in version control of the Android Studio `Log window`.

> Normally I take the things related to git or version control seriously
> so after merging I double-checked the changes of that
> `*(Asterisk)` commit and the changes were there after merging. So
> technically there is nothing wrong with the code and everything seems
> perfect.

But still, if anyone knows what this `*(Asterisk)` means I would love to hear your thoughts?

Thanks in advance :)

[image: Android studio VCS Log window screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the author and commiter are different. Can happen, for example, if A cherry-pick's B's commits, or if A rebases a branch containing commits by B.

In the commit description (in the lower right) you should see, below the message and author, something like "Commited by XXXX".